# (A room / an office) where an artist works

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-request

What do you call a place including an office or a room where an artist (e.g. a photographer or a painter) works?
I know the word "**atelier**" which based on Cambridge Dictionary's definition is something [literary](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/atelier) or based on MacMillan Dictionary a [formal](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.macmillandictionary.com/amp/dictionary/british/atelier) word.

However, I need a word which doesn't sound literary or fancy and totally weird in everyday speech to talk about such a place. I wonder what word works properly in this sense if "atelier" doesn't?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

A [**studio**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/studio) is a working space for an artist.

> 1. **a**: the working place of a painter, sculptor, or photographer
>
>    **b**: a place for the study of an art (such as dancing, singing, or
>             acting)

Comment: Thank you @fjack, but I wonder what's wrong with "atelier"?

Comment: I have a larger vocabulary than most of the people I associate with, and I still had to look up _atelier_. Almost anyone will understand _studio_; I suspect that even many of those who _do_ know what _atelier_ means will form a negative opinion of the person who actually _uses_ the word (the politest opinion likely being "stuck-up").

Comment: @A-friend There's nothing wrong with *atelier*. Except that you, yourself, ruled it out in the question, saying it's literary and that you were looking for something *else*.

Comment: I'm from the US and have literally never encountered the word atelier outside of the video game series. Seems it's a French word that's sometimes used in English, but certainly not in my area.

Comment: Actually "atelier" is simply the French word for the space. Using French words, especially for artistic things, can sound more *refined*.

Comment: "Atelier" is a French word.  It is commonly seen here in Germany, though, rather than "studio."  "Atelier" sounds stuck up when used in English, but is a completely normal word in German - and presumably in French as well.

Comment: "Atelier" is used as a professional term in English, but it usually means a *group* of artists or students working together under the leadership of one person, and usually working as a commercial organisation, for example producing jewellery or fashion. It is not the right word to refer to an individual artist working alone.

Comment: Another reason to avoid "atelier" in English here is that one of your examples was a photographer, and that combination is never used; if it was it would seem very pretentious, much more so than for a painter (for whom it would still be rare)